# Windows Security Center Not Recognizing Third Party Utilities After System Restore

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, firewall, system-restore, security-center

I am running Windows XP Professional 64-bit.  I recently had to do a system restore, after Windows Update blue-screened my machine while updating the network driver.  The system restore went without a hitch, and everything is working as it was, except for the Windows Security Center.  Now, it is not recognizing the Comodo firewall and Avast anti-virus that I having running.  I have verified that both are running in the task bar and the task manager.  Does anyone know how to get Windows to recognize them again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=23457